# Change position of badge in TDBadgedCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am new to Objective-C development, currently working on my very first iOS App. 
I want to display a badge symbol in UITableView cells. For this i found the [TDBadgedCell Class on GitHub](https://github.com/tmdvs/TDBadgedCell).
I have derived my own UITableViewCell class from TDBadgedCell and basically it works fine.

My problem is now, i want to change the position of the badge inside my cells. I think this is not supported directly by the api, but i am trying to find a way to do this.
I've played around with the badge property of the cell, which is an UIView object, but it does not work:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MCLThread *thread = self.threads[indexPath.row];
    MCLThreadTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ThreadCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.badgeString = thread.answerCount;

    NSLog(@"Before: %f", cell.badge.frame.origin.y);

    // Try to move badge
    CGRect badgeFrame = cell.badge.frame;
    badgeFrame.origin = CGPointMake(badgeFrame.origin.x, 35); // y = 35
    cell.badge.frame = badgeFrame;

    NSLog(@"After: %f", cell.badge.frame.origin.y);    

    return cell;
}
```

The log output shows that the y-coordinate is changed, but the badge is still on the same position in the running app.

```
2014-08-26 14:50:25.494 mclient[66574:60b] Before: 21.000000
2014-08-26 14:50:25.549 mclient[66574:60b] After: 35.000000
```

The same approach has worked for me to dynamically set the position for some UILabel objects in the same cell (i've removed this from the code above).

Can someone tell me what's the difference here or what's the correct way to implement my intention?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you try changing the origin in tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: ?

Comment: @EDUsta I've tried it, it has also no effect :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I didn't properly read your answer, here's my suggestion
edit badgeframe
in TDBadgedCell.m

```
- (void) layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    if(self.badgeString)
    {
    [[self contentView] addSubview:[self badge]];

    // Force badges to hide on edit.
    if(self.editing)
        [self.badge setHidden:YES];
    else
        [self.badge setHidden:NO];

    // Calculate the size of the bage from the badge string
    UIFont *font = self.badge.boldFont ? [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:self.badge.fontSize] : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:self.badge.fontSize];

    CGSize badgeSize;
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:@"7.0" options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending) {
        badgeSize = [self.badgeString sizeWithAttributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName:font }];
    } else {
        badgeSize = [self.badgeString sizeWithFont:font];
    }
```

EDIT THIS PART

```
//HERE STITCH EDIT ME PLEASE

CGRect badgeframe = CGRectMake(self.contentView.frame.size.width - (badgeSize.width + 13 + self.badgeRightOffset),
                                   (CGFloat)round((self.contentView.frame.size.height - (badgeSize.height + (50/badgeSize.height))) / 2),
                                   badgeSize.width + 13, badgeSize.height + (50/badgeSize.height));
```

Comment: Thank you, yes this will work of course, but is IMO not very satisfying. If nobody knows a solution without modifying the external class i think i will fork the repo on github and add a method to setup the coordinates.

Comment: I'm saying the class is not as flexible as what you want it to be. The solution is to make it better externally to fit your needs. I just thought you need a fast solution. Anyway goodluck.